# Access Azure AD Graph API in ASP.NET MVC Organizational account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to restrict page access based on logged in user's AD Groups. I have issues with following codes.

```
   var tenantId = incomingPrincipal.FindFirst(GraphConfiguration.TenantIdClaimType).Value;

 //create Azure Graph Api client to make api calls
 var client = Helpers.AzureGraphAPIFunctions.GetActiveDirectoryClient(tenantId);

 IGroup group = client.Groups.Where(x => x.DisplayName == groupName).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
```

These codes work fine and get me the AD Group by groupName but sometimes throws exception

> "Tenant information is not available locally. Use the following Urls
>   to get the information."

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Directory_BindingRedirection","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Tenant information is not available locally. Use the following Urls to get the information."},
"values":[
          {"item":"Url1","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-ch1.directory.windows.net"},
          {"item":"Url2","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-sn2.directory.windows.net"},
          {"item":"Url3","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-co1.directory.windows.net"},
          {"item":"Url4","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-bl2.directory.windows.net"}
         ]}}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folks,

We're currently investigating this issue (you should not be seeing this error).  It looks like a regression.  Will update this thread when I have more info.

**UPDATE**:
This issue should now be resolved.  We made an update to our gateway logic that broke some of our retry/redirect logic.  We've now put some monitors in place also that should detect this issue much faster (should we make the same mistake again).

Apologies for those of you who were affected by this incident.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Let me know when you have update.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing it.

Comment: @dan-kershaw-msft Is it possible this is happening again today? Or could it be something on our end?

Comment: We are seeing the same thing here, it started approx 13 hours ago.