# Directory_BindingRedirection error on running a differential query against Azure AD

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an application that performs a query against Azure AD. Running a bog-standard GET for users works perfectly:

```
https://graph.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/users?api-version=2013-04-05
```

But if I attempt a differential query:

```
https://graph.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/users?api-version=2013-04-05&deltaLink=
```

I get the following error:

```
{ 
 "odata.error":
    {
     "code":"Directory_BindingRedirection",
     "message":{"lang":"en","value":"Tenant information is not available locally. Use the following Urls to get the information."},
     "values":[
       {"item":"Url1","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-ch1.directory.windows.net"},
       {"item":"Url2","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-sn2.directory.windows.net"},
       {"item":"Url3","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-bl2.directory.windows.net"},
       {"item":"Url4","value":"https:\/\/directory-s1-co1.directory.windows.net"}]
    }
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609043/access-azure-ad-graph-api-in-asp-net-mvc-organizational-account) suggests that this may be a problem with AzureAD, rather than an expected error case that should be coded for - is this the case, or should this error be handled as per the instructions contained within..?

Comment: No, this isn't something your should need to code for. Can you confirm you're still seeing this?

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Yes, still seeing the same issue

Comment: I should also add, I've been seeing this error for a few days - I think I got the first cut of code together on Thursday last week, so that was the first time I saw the issue. I haven't managed to run a successful differential at all, either before or since.

Comment: Thanks, one more question: Do you see the same behavior with a more recent API versions (e.g. 1.5 or 1.6)?

Comment: Yes, same issue with api-version=1.5 and api-version=1.6